# TCP port number - android phone usb connected

Tags: android, android-emulator

How do I get the TCP port number for a usb connected android phone. I can do this

```
   netstat -an |find /i "listening"
```

but then it lists all the listening port, how do I know to which port my phone is listening to. anyone on this pls?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you are trying to do here but if your phone is connected via USB then it does not have a TCP port open it is addressed via the USB device. Take a look at the AdbTest example program provided with the API.

You can get [Adb to connect over wifi](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html) (see bootom of this page) but I believe that in most cases this requires a rooted device.

Comment: I was trying to see the network traffic through wireshark and was following [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/analyzing-android-network-traffic/) post, which uses `adb forward tcp:12345 tcp:54321` command . But I got stuck as I could not find out the android phone port number(and I could be wrong here as I am new to this stuff). Is there any other way of analysing http traffic in android. I've also tried [this](http://www.cantoni.org/2011/06/28/debug-http-android-fiddler) but couldnt get it working. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There are many steps and options in that post. Firstly if you are trying the final option of piping directly to wireshark then you need to have followed the preceding steps. There is no "Android port" to be found you are specifying all the ports in the command-line, you get to choose. What is happening is that in option 1, the tcpdump captures to a file. in option 2 they tell you how to divert the tcpdump output to netcat (nc) which publishes it on a port that you specify (12345) in their example.

Comment: In option 3, they use adb to capture all the traffic on the port that you were diverting the output to (12345) and republish it to port 54321 (again you can change this) on the localhost (the machine you are running the adb session on) they then show you how to capture this in wireshark by using netcat on the localhost to republish so that wioreshark can capture it. If all of this is alien I would start with the simple option to capture to file on the handset and then pull the file back and load it in manually.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand now what you are saying. Yes, I've performed all the steps before giving that particular command. I've directed the traffic to `port 4573` which was listening on `127.0.0.1` and then tried to forward the port by using `adb forward tcp:4573 tcp:5354 && nc 127.0.0.1 5354 | wireshark -k -S -i -`. `port 5354` was also listening on `127.0.0.1`.  I am getting `cannot bind socket` error. I am trying to read on that. Pls let me know if you know anything about this error. Thanks again.